# How to mock a function which gets executed during the import time?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest.mock

Here the `ABC()` and `obj.print_1()` get called during the import time and it prints "making object" and "printed 1" respectively. How can we mock all the three functions, `__init__()`, `print_1()`, and `print_2()`?

**xyz.py**

```
from abc import ABC
obj = ABC()
obj.print_1()

def func():
   return obj.print_2(2)
```

**abc.py**

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
       print("making object")
       
    def print_1(self):
        print("printed 1")
        return None
    
   def print_2(self, val):
       print("printed ", val)
       return None
```

Comment: Consider whether `obj` should be defined at import time at all, or if it should be created by a function that the importer can call *after* importing `xyz.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as soon as you import `xyz`, it will import `abc` and create an instance then call a method on it.

Solution : import `abc` yourself **BEFORE** `xyz` **EVER GETS IMPORTED**, and mock the methods defined in the class. And because we can't import a method, [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) is required.

Note : I added a `self` as parameter in your `ABC.print_1` method, otherwise it would be incorrect. Otherwise make it [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Here is the test file I used :

```py
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

from so74709409_abc import ABC

# no import of `xyz` here !

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test__xyz_obj_calls_print1(self):
        #                                     __init__ must return None
        with mock.patch.object(ABC, "__init__", **{"return_value": None}) as mock_init, \
             mock.patch.object(ABC, "print_1") as mock_print1, \
             mock.patch.object(ABC, "print_2") as mock_print2:
                from so74709409_xyz import func  # import now !
                func()
        mock_init.assert_called_once()
        mock_print1.assert_called_once_with()
        mock_print2.assert_called_once_with(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But this is not very robust, if the module was already imported (maybe indirectly) before the test run, the `import` inside the test won't have any effect, and so it will fail (mocks not getting called). It can be a pain in a real test suite (with many tests running in sequence) because the previous test will already have imported `xyz`.

That's why it's better to do these kind of things in a `if __name__=="__main__"`, or in a function called deliberately.

<sub>(beware : I assume you choose `abc` as a dummy name, but it is actually a standard library module for [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html))</sub>

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I chose ABC as a dummy name.